# matlab: saved figure corrupted by background

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I am running matlab R2014a on Ubuntu 14.04, when I save plots using the menu on the figure window --

[image]

the figure is saved, but they get corrupted like this --

[image]

and also like this --

[image]

what I think, when I click the 'save' button, there is a delay during the capture of the image.

how do I fix it ?

just to let you know that I am doing a trivial plot --

```
figure(5)
surf(real(fmu))
zlim([0 2])
```

also, `saveas()` command gives a similar output.

Comment: Have you try to change the renderer option ? `set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'YourChoice');`

Comment: Try using the "print" command instead of "saveas"